# How can I solve a system of 'n' (non linear) equations with 'n' variables (second degree polynomial) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is possible to solve a system of 'n' (no linear) equations with 'n' variables (grade 2 or 1) in Matlab?

Can you point me an example?

I've tried to use `fsolve` function but the next error appear:

`??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'ecuaciones' for input arguments of type
'double'.`

[example with fsolve](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN4gMygK8Uw)

Edited:

I've a file called 'ecuaciones.m' which has the next content:

```
function [f]=ecuaciones(x)

f(1)=x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + 2*x(4) -1,905;
f(2)=2*x(3) + 3*x(4) + x(5) + x(6) - 3,922;
f(3)=x(1) + 2*x(2) + x(4) + x(5) + x(6) - 1,961;
f(4)=1,961*x(3) + x(3)*x(5) - x(2)*x(3) - 0,02834*(x(5)^2);
f(5)=9,32845*(x(3)^2) - x(4)*x(6);
f(6)=61,4723*x(1)*x(6) - x(2)*x(5);


J = zeros (n,n);

J =

[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1]
[ 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[ 0, -x3, x5 - x2 + 1961/1000, 0, x3 - (1417*x5)/25000, 0]
[ 0, 0, (2625725246496519*x3)/140737488355328, -x6, 0, -x4]
[ (8651457105425229*x6)/140737488355328, -x5, 0, 0, -x2, (8651457105425229*x1)/140737488355328];
```

Then, in Matlab console I try:

```
>> x0=[1,1,1,1,1,1];
>> [x,feval,flag]=fsolve('ecuaciones',x0);
```

Comment: the error msg is informing you that there is no `ecuaciones` function defined.

Comment: I've edited the question. @Shai: I don't know the exactly traduction in English. When I say 'grade' 2, it means that a variable is (for example): x^2

Comment: second grade is a second order polynomial

Comment: Do not use commas in real numbers, use decimal point instead! `f(1)=x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + 2*x(4) -1,905;` is equivalent to `f(1)=x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + 2*x(4) -1; 905;` and this is not you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function handle

```
 >> x = fsolve( @ecuaciones, x0 );
```

You need to make sure `ecuaciones.m` is in matlab's path.

**UPDATE:**
for better convergence, you might want to compute the Jacobian as well.
In your case, the Jacobian is an `n` by `n` matrix with `J(l,k)` is the partial derivative of `f(l)` w.r.t `x(k)` at the point **`x`**.
You will need to modify `ecuaciones.m` to return **two** outputs the first is `f` and the second is `J`

```
function [f J] = ecuaciones( x )

f(1)=x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + 2*x(4) -1,905;
f(2)=2*x(3) + 3*x(4) + x(5) + x(6) - 3,922;
f(3)=x(1) + 2*x(2) + x(4) + x(5) + x(6) - 1,961;
f(4)=1,961*x(3) + x(3)*x(5) - x(2)*x(3) - 0,02834*(x(5)^2);
f(5)=9,32845*(x(3)^2) - x(4)*x(6);
f(6)=61,4723*x(1)*x(6) - x(2)*x(5);

J = [...
      1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0;...
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;...
      0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1;...
      1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1;...
      0, -x3, x5 - x2 + 1961/1000, 0, x3 - (1417*x5)/25000, 0;...
      0, 0, (2625725246496519*x3)/140737488355328, -x6, 0, -x4;...
      (8651457105425229*x6)/140737488355328, -x5, 0, 0, -x2, (8651457105425229*x1)/140737488355328];
```

And you may call `fsolve`

```
>> x = fsolve( @ecuaciones, x0, struct('Jacobian','on') );
```

Comment: It seems like the function `ecuaciones.m` is not in your matlab's path. change directory to the same folder as `ecuaciones.m` and try again.

Comment: I obtain the next error: `??? Undefined function or method 'optimoptions' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

Comment: How could I modify the equations in `ecuaciones.m`?

Comment: I don't know what modification I have to do in `ecuaciones.m`

Comment: @vicenrele - you need to compute `J` as well in `ecuaciones.m` see the definition of `J(l,k)` in my answer. You need to do this computation yourself, given the coefficients of the equations.

Comment: Ok, @Shai. But what is the notation that I want to use? I've the Jacobian matrix, but how can I add it in `ecuaciones.m`. Below function [f J] = ecuaciones( x ).

Comment: @vicenrele -matlab function can return several outputs. see my edit.

Comment: Where you write "% put computation of J here", I've put the Jacobian matrix, but I obtain an error for the matrix code: `Expression or statement is incomplete or incorrect.` I've edited the question

Comment: I've obtained the expression with Matlab, calculating the Jacobian matrix

Comment: Thanks for help. Now, I obtain the next error: `Reference to non-existent field 'JacobMult'.Error in ==> fsolve at 294
    if isempty(options.JacobMult)`